# How do I have referenced key:value update when their referenced key:value updates in a class?

Tags: python

In the code below, how can I change the set_ref method so that it automatically changes to value of the reference key to match the value of the key it is referencing every time I print sheet?

For Example:

In the code below, I set A1 value to 10, then I use the set_ref method to make A3 reference A1 so it's also 10. Now when I set value of A1 to 20, A3 is still 10. What do I need to do to automatically get A3 value to change to 20?

```
#create sheets class with constructor to initialize "cells" instance variable as a dictionary

class Sheet:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.cells = dict()

    # set_value method takes key as a string and value as an int, set cells with
    # key index along with its value
    def set_value(self, key: string, value: int) -> None:
        self.cells[key] = value

    # get_value method takes the key as a string and return the value of the cell
    # based on key index
    def get_value(self, key: string) -> int:
        return self.cells[key]
        
    # set ref takes new key, the reference key and the old key, the key being referenced
    # use set value method to set new value that has new key and the value of the key that it references
    def set_ref(self, ref_key: string, key:string):
         self.set_value(ref_key, self.cells[key])
         
    # repr dunder method returns output as a string
    # for each key in all the cells:
    # add to the output= key: and its value and return key:value pair to us
    def __repr__(self):
        output = "--------\n"
        for key in self.cells.keys():
            output += f'{key}: {self.get_value(key)}\n'
        output += "--------"
        return output


# sheet object instantiation
sheet = Sheet()

sheet.set_value('A1', 10)

sheet.set_ref('A3', 'A1') 

print(sheet) # A3 is now 10, just like A1

sheet.set_value('A1', 20)

print(sheet)  # A3 is still 10, not 20
```

Comment: You need an extra level of indirection. For example, `self.cells` can contain "regular" values *or* `Cell` instances, where a `Cell` instance is just a wrapper around a cell name. When `get_value` finds a `Cell` instance in `self.cells`, it has to do another lookup to find the value of *that* cell, instead of returning the `Cell` instance directly. `set_ref`, then, has to add a `Cell` reference to the sheet, instead of simply copying the *value* of one cell to another.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing both sample data and an example of required output along with the code that produces your problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: Can we assume that the key is always `str` and the value is always `int`?

Comment: Yes, Key's are always str and values are always int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that keys are always `str` and values are always `int` you can tweak your code a bit:

```
class Sheet:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.cells = dict()

    # set_value method takes key as a string and value as an int, set cells with
    # key index along with its value
    def set_value(self, key: str, value: int) -> None:
        self.cells[key] = value

    # get_value method takes the key as a string and return the value of the cell
    # based on key index
    def get_value(self, key: str) -> int:
        if type(self.cells[key]) == int:
            return self.cells[key]
        return self.get_value(self.cells[key])
        
    # set ref takes new key, the reference key and the old key, the key being referenced
    # use set value method to set new value that has new key and the value of the key that it references
    def set_ref(self, ref_key: str, key:str):
         self.set_value(ref_key, key)
         
    # repr dunder method returns output as a string
    # for each key in all the cells:
    # add to the output= key: and its value and return key:value pair to us
    def __repr__(self):
        output = "--------\n"
        for key in self.cells.keys():
            output += f'{key}: {self.get_value(key)}\n'
        output += "--------"
        return output


# sheet object instantiation
sheet = Sheet()

sheet.set_value('A1', 10)

sheet.set_ref('A3', 'A1') 

print(sheet) # A3 is now 10, just like A1

sheet.set_value('A1', 20)

print(sheet)
```

output:

```
--------
A1: 10
A3: 10
--------
--------
A1: 20
A3: 20
--------
```

Methods signatures stay the same.

We are now setting two kinds of values: the value itself (which is `int`) or a ref (which is type `str`).

The secret is while receiving the value (`get_value`): we check the value's type; if it's an `int` - that's the final value. Else, we recursively calls to `get_value` with the key that is stored in that cell..

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible for you to give me a quick explanation on what set_ref and get_value is now doing?  set_ref seems to now contain set_value taking 2 keys as arguements. I'm not sure what the purpose of that would be.

Comment: You can thank me by upvoting & accept the answer. I will edit my answer with explanation :)

Comment: Ofcourse, both are done!